# Weird Mesh on exporting As fbx from blender

Tags: mesh, export, .fbx

So I recently made a 3d model of a spaceship for my game. I tried to export it as fbx so that I can use it in unity. but the exported object is distorted/stretched.

[image: This is the Actual spaceship]

[image: The problem..]

[image: Back]

[image]

Honestly I don't even know what this abomination is. As soon as I export the fbx and try to open it in unity, this is what I get.

Comment: Make sure you set the rotation and scale in blender before exporting. Also remember that unity is Y-up, wheras blender is Z-up. I think you can specify that in the export settings.

Comment: Yes, I have the position and rotations for x, y and z at 0. I have tried changing the settings at export too but for no avail.

Comment: Hmmm. What about scale? I'm just thinking that if you have something scaled on the Y axis in blender, it may interpret that as "scale up and down" in unity.

Comment: Apart from applying scale for the object (Object mode, object selected, Ctrl+A) try to see if there are any shape keys. It looks like mesh deformation although there doesn't appear to be any modifiers (if there are any turn them on to see result in Blender or delete to avoid them being applied on export)

Comment: Tried the scale solution too.. still its just an abomination. No modifiers used. Guess i'll remake it that'll take less time as compared to solving it